# Ecplise View flow of running program

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, call, hierarchy

I'm currently writing a pretty large program that calls the same methods from different places.
Now I would really like to see how the program goes from one method to another as it is running. Like a live view that shows when what method is opened (and why?). Call Hierarchy doesn't suit my needs at this point. Is there a way?

Comment: Have you tried adding breakpoints and stepping through the code?

Comment: No, how does that work?

Answer (score 1):

One way to follow the logic of your application is by placing breakpoints at the line of code you want your application to stop at but, to do this you'll have to setup it up in debug mode.

Every major IDE will let you do this, including Eclipse. 
Have a look at this tutorial:
[Java Debugging with Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Once you setup your program in debug mode you can add a breakpoint in the gutter next to the line numbers.

[image: What a breakpoint looks like]